# Testing for Heteroskedasticity, along variables, using the White Test in r

Tags: r, regression

I wanted to test which variables of Ordinary Least Squares regression (OLS)  are Heteroskedastic, using the White Test, in R. I know how to use the white.test{bstats} in R. However, this function only tells us whether Heteroskedasticity is present or not; it does not tell us which variables are causing it (if Heteroskedasticity is present).
I was wondering if there is a function in R that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Based on `library(sos);findFn("white test")`, less likely. If you can get the paper that `white.test` function is mentioning, perhaps you could code your own test?

Comment: Thanks for your input Roman. Perhaps I will have to do that. Just wanted to check if such a function already existed (didn't know about findFn()). I shall await a few more responses before deciding to code it up.